# How do you stay focused in advanced (pure) mathematics lectures?

Tags: soft-question, advice

Throughout my entire university career, I've found it incredibly difficult to focus during lectures, so much so that I at one point stopped going because I found it easier to just learn it on my own. A clarification: I did not find learning it on my own easy, just easier than lectures since I always get incredibly tired, and can't stay focused. Unfortunately, I've reached a point where I can't just "learn it one my own", since some classes are very specialized or deal with difficult areas of pure math.

So, how do you focus during lectures (specifically math lectures)?

Comment: It is hugely helpful to skim through the contents of the lecture *before* the lecture. You don't have to study it in detail, but this way you will at least know what's coming.

Comment: What really helped me was reading the material beforehand. When I went to class already having some idea of the material, the lecture seemed to elaborate on points that I didn’t understand (or had difficulty understanding). If the lecture didn’t address these directly, I’d ask about it.

Comment: I agree, thank you for your answer! I should have been more specific though, I'm mostly looking for what to do during a lectur, although reading before hand is definitely helpful.

Comment: During tougher lectures I was often unable stay focused for a full two hours (without getting a headache). I fully support the comments by MisterRiemann and Clayton, and would like to add that it is valuable to recognize which details of a lecture you can afford to miss while continuing to follow the main points of the lecture. Often there were tedious or subtle details that I was not able to follow immediately, but was confident I could figure out own my own at a later point. Treat them as a given, have a little daydream, and continue to follow at the next point.

Comment: Not being able to focus could be due to certain brain chemistry issues that may be easily fixed. Aside from this, try to use the lecture time to study and verify what you are hearing and try to come up with questions (event to yourself), Plan not to be passive during the lecture.

Comment: That is exactly what I’m responding to, actually. Having an idea of what was going on meant I was actually understanding most of the lecture. This was enough for me to stay awake. If I don’t understand what is going on, I tend to become sleepy and will either nod off or become distracted with something else so i can at least not be so rude as to fall asleep in class. :)

Comment: Try to keep things 'unknown' and operate with them. E.g. if there's a definition of X that you couldn't properly follow, then any theorem about X may *help* you understand what X really means, even if keeping X as a blank unknown in your mind..

Comment: Take notes. During my Physics degree a toke notes of every subject and everything was perfect. Now I'm going to two math subjects just for fun. I take notes in one but not in the other. The result is that I enjoy one (the first) but I get sleep in the other. So take notes, even if you don't understand what are you writing. That's my advice.